# Requires a query that can report the last 100 queries executed in SQL Server along with their execution time and the user who executed it

Tags: sql-server

I found the following queries on the internet. The first query is for receiving 100 queries executed on the server,

```
SELECT TOP 100
    deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time],
    dest.text AS [Query] , *
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS apply
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY
    deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

and the second query displays the users registered in SQL Server.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sql_logins
```

My question is how can I connect these two queries in such a way that it shows the users who have run the queries in the list. Thanks ...

Comment: You can't, it's not information that is saved. Bear in mind that multiple users may have excuted the same query. If you need better tracking, setup auditing

Answer (score 0):

As Charlieface says in the comments, you should set up Auditing to track who is executing what query & when. You can find information about SQL Server Auditing, including how to set it up, on Microsoft Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine

Once you have auditing set up as you want it, you can then execute the following to find the details of the most recent 100 queries:

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM sys.fn_get_audit_file ('\\serverName\foldername\filename.sqlaudit',default,default)
ORDER BY event_time DESC;
```